# How do I notify my Client that my Consultancy Agreement is expiring & also I want them to renew it

Tags: freelance-websites, consulting, writing

I am a Consultant to a company whose HR, PD & other people have not notified me that the agreement is expiring in a few days. I want to send an email to the CEO, HR, PD and do the following:

1. Inform the CEO that my agreement is expiring
2. I also want to ask them to renew it
3. I need a heads up (30 day prior notice) when the contract is expiring or they decide to terminate it

How do I put this in the email?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - how do you not know when your contract is expiring?

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why this warrants a question here. It seems **very** straightforward to me.

> Hello [CEO],
>
> Our consultancy contract is due to expire on XXXX.
>
> I would be pleased to renew the contract.
>
> Please let me know by [Date] if you wish to renew.
>
> Thank you.